# Adding Job Dependancy between Spring Batch Jobs

Tags: spring, cron, spring-batch

I am having two Jobs A and B. Both of which gets triggered based on Cron Expression.

I am looking for way where Job B gets triggered when two conditions get satisfied.

- Job A gets completed Successfully.
- Cron Expression is triggered.

Comment: Do you mean that B should not fire until the cron trigger after A is complete or is A being kicked off by the cron trigger good enough?

Comment: Basically Job B should be triggered when Job A completed and Time Dependacy (Cron Tab) is met.   If Any one of these two conditions is not satisfied then job B should not start.

Comment: What I meant is if Job A is run only via cron, and Job B only runs after Job A, the time dependency for Job B will always be met, right?

Comment: Right , I am wondering how can we have these dependancy